# Ruby 1.9.3 with rvm on Mac Lion installs, but doesn't show up in Ruby or irb

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rvm

On Mac OS X running Lion 10.7.3 and having Xcode 4.3.2, I find that installing ruby 1.9.3 through rvm and setting default to use 1.9.3 still shows ruby -v to be 1.8.7 (irb RUBY_VERSION also shows 1.8.7).

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
<installs successfully>
$ rvm --default 1.9.3
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
$ irb
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
```

How do I get ruby and irb to use ruby 1.9.3 on this configuration?

Update: Looks like I had an older version of rvm. I installed Jewelry Box (OS X rvm GUI tool), which reinstalled rvm, and then updated the ruby to use from within jewelry box. This did the trick. Thanks all for your help.

Thanks

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` output?

Comment: /Users/rcanand/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: Is this after running the `rvm use` command? It looks like the RVM directory is not on your path...

Comment: Your path ought to start with /Users/rcanand/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:. The ruby you find is in /usr/bin.

What does `rvm list` say?

Answer (score 6):

If you have successfully installed ruby 1.9.3

then you can check it by this command either installed or not

```
     rvm list
```

then all rubies listing will be display...

then if you select any rubu version use this command

```
 rvm use ruby-1.9.3  --default
```

and enjoying.........

Comment: rvm list shows the new version 1.9.3. However, even after calling rvm use ruby-1.9.3 --default, ruby version shows 1.8.7

Comment: You first create gemset for your app in which you use ruby-1.9.3          use this command   "rvm gemset create appName                                                       " then use this command  "rvm use ruby-1.9.2@appName                            "  hence you can choose ruby 1.9.3 for this application

Comment: Please update your answer with the last comment. I will accept as answer - that is indeed the change that Jewelry Box seems to have done for me (see my edit). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`rvm get head` will update your RVM installation in place to the current release. It's a good idea to do that periodically, just to keep up with the bug fixes and new features.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and wanted to post my solution as it may be helpful for someone. I switched to 1.9.3 in my terminal window and then opened another window to use IRB in that window. When I did

```
RUBY_VERSION
```

in IRB it told me I was using 1.8.7. I realized after that I shouldn't have opened another window to do it. It works just fine if I stay in the same window, make sure I am using 1.9.3 and then go into IRB from there.

Thought someone else might have a use case like mine and this would help.